# log transform X axis R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the following raw data that I plotted in R:

[image]

And I would like to edit this plot to look like this version below which was made by log-transforming the X axis using Excel

[image]

However, when I run my code below using scale_x_log10(), the output is not the desired plot I was hoping to make. See image below:

[image]

Can anyone identify where I have gone wrong?

```
ggplot(data = data, aes(x = x, y = y, group = group, color = group)) +
  stat_summary(fun = "mean", geom = "line", size = 1.2, aes(group = group, linetype = group, color = group)) +
  stat_summary(fun = "mean", geom = "point", size = 3, aes(color = group)) +
  theme_apa() +
  scale_linetype_manual(values = c("solid", "dashed")) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("mediumturquoise", "red")) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = scales::pretty_breaks(n = 10)) +
  scale_x_log10(limits = c(.01, 40), breaks = c(.01, .1, 1, 10))
```

Comment: At the green line there is one point missing. Perhaps is this a first approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your first datapoint is at zero - this can't be displayed on a log scale. You'll need to work out if there's a difference in you data in excel, failing that you could achieve a similar result by modifying the lowest value of x with:

```
ggplot(data = data, aes(x = pmax(x,0.01), y = y, group = group, color = group)) +
  stat_summary(fun = "mean", geom = "line", size = 1.2, aes(group = group, linetype = group, color = group)) +
  stat_summary(fun = "mean", geom = "point", size = 3, aes(color = group)) +
  theme_apa() +
  scale_linetype_manual(values = c("solid", "dashed")) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("mediumturquoise", "red")) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = scales::pretty_breaks(n = 10)) +
  scale_x_log10(limits = c(.01, 40), breaks = c(.01, .1, 1, 10))
```

Comment: Yes, this is correct. Thank you! The lowest point is zero and the desired output is achieved when 0 is changed to .01 - thanks for the help